# Spring Batch DB setup scripts not getting run on Unix

Tags: spring-batch, derby, spring-jdbc

We have a Spring Batch application which, for development, uses an embedded Derby database. When run from within IntelliJ, or as a jar on windows, the Derby database is created as we expect. In addition, the scripts to setup the database are run.

This is all defined in configuration in `launch-context.xml`.

Our setup is standard:

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="derbyDataSource" />
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
   <property name="databaseType" value="derby" />
</bean>

<bean id="derbyDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:sql/dartpublisher;create=true"/>
   <property name="username" value=""/>
   <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="derbyDataSource" />
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="derbyDataSource" ignore-failures="ALL" enabled="true">
   <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-derby.sql" />
   <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-derby.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

When we run on Unix, the Derby database also gets created as expected, and the files which we expect to see are there.

However, it appears that the database setup script is not getting run, as this exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' does not exist.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' does not exist.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
        ... 48 more
```

This is how the Spring application is getting bootstrapped:

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.load("app-context.xml");
ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
ctx.refresh();
ctx.start();
```

The code or configuration has not changed - does anyone know what the issue may be?

Thanks

Comment: How are you launching these jobs?

Comment: JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);

Comment: Sorry, I mean't how is the context being bootstrapped...

Comment: Have updated the question to include the bootstrapping, thanks

Comment: Are you overriding the username/password when you connect to the DB? Is it possible that sometimes you connect as UserA, and othertimes you connect as UserB, and hence UserB doesn't see the tables created in UserA's schema?

Comment: Interesting, but not that I am aware of - think the only derby configuration is as above

Comment: You could try removing the `ignore-failures="ALL"` from your `jdbc:initialize-database` tag to check if the execution of the sql scripts is maybe raising errors.